# wordpress installation in localhost

Tags: wordpress, parsing, installation, server, local

I tried to install wordpress site from server to local machine.I got the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\beta\wp-content\themes\canvas\header.php on line 4375

Comment: How did you move the site? Could you provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you have a syntax error in your theme.

Make sure you remove the closing php tag "?>" at the end of your wp-content/themes/canvas/functions.php file of that theme. Additionally removing any trailing blank lines at the end of the functions.php file.